# Past perfect continuous and use of since

Tags: adverbs, past-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

I came across the following sentence with an instruction to rewrite it in past perfect continuous using the given time expression in brackets:

- Govind was working in this factory as a watchman. (since he came to Delhi)

My answer:

- Govind had been working in this factory as a watchman since he came to Delhi.

I am kind of confused now as Govind first came to Delhi then he started working, but I'm using 'had' with working which action-wise happens afterwards.

If I could use 'since 2010' or 'since January' then it would make sense but I have to use 'came'(simple past). So, can someone please help.

Comment: *"since he came to Delhi"* is a subordinate clause, and subordinate clauses are not affected by the tense in the main clause.

Comment: If *since 2010* and *since January* make sense, then so should *since he came to Delhi*. But the sentence might make more sense if you reversed it: *Since he came to Delhi, Govind had been working in this factory as a watchman.*

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.